# Android - Add Lomo effect to images

Tags: android, image, effect, lomo-effect

I googled a lot but couldn't come up with a satisfying answer.

I want to add a "Lomo" effect to images I process in my app.

I tried these libraries but the first one doesn't have "Lomo effect" and the second one uses the Android NDK...

- https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage
- https://github.com/ragnraok/android-image-filte

Does anybody know an easy solution for adding `Lomo`?

Comment: you can use image tint

Comment: Thanks Biraj Zalavadia. So is it possible to get the lomo effect using image tint?. Does anybody know now?